# How are electrons increased in voltage in batteries?

Tags: electricity

A battery could be made of a series of cells each delivering for example 2 volt. Because they are in some way connected to each other the electrons get a final voltage of 12 volt. But how can the line up of cells cause an increase of the voltage?

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't?  The basic answer is that voltage adds if you put cells in a series 2+2+2+2+2+2 = 12.  If you don't think they add, what do you think they do?  That might help better form answers that will help you.

Comment: I know they add, and I don't doubt about it, but I only want to know how this happen?

Comment: Do you understand how a single cell generates 2 volts?  There's two parts to the problem.  One is how a chemical reaction can generate an electric field, and the second part is how electric fields are additive.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare it to water pumps. Imagine you have a bucket placed 1m above the ground and then a second bucket placed 2m above the ground. You also have 2 pumps, each one capable of pumping water to a maximum height of 1m. Now you can simply use one of the pumps to get the water to the first bucket and the second pump to move it from the first to the second bucket.

Comment: Thanks for this analogy but I'm actually looking not for this comparison but how it works in batteries with electrons. Or is it more than an analogy and only a differences of forces (electromagnetism vs gravity)?

Comment: It cannot be exactly the same, i'm fairly sure. for example, let's take a pipe filled with water and pumps on the way up (representing the battery) and it falls on the way down. The energy here is a function of height and suppose there is enough friction in the pipes to allow the water to remain at constant speed at all points. That is fine except we are left with the problem of modeling a resistor in series

Comment: the only way to model a resistor here is to have some device that decreases height more than the rest of the system. Therefore the only way to model a resistor is to have a longer section of pipe placed in series where water is flowing downwards. But we cannot do this without increasing the voltage (height) of the battery

Comment: The analogy is not perfect. Water behaves quite differently from electricity. If you want the full truth, take a look at [this discussion](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/e-field-inside-wires-during-transient-state.846108). Electrons in a wire are always pushed by an electric field (or quantum effects in e.g. semiconductors). They don't push each other directly. Unlike water molecules.

Comment: the only way to do this would be to have some device that compresses and decompresses space along the length of the pipe. Then, ohms law may apply if we consider the volume of water passing a point per second to be current as long as 1/area is resistance where area*height between two points must be the same in uncompressed space

Comment: there is a common analogy that p/A = v is voltage and 1/A is the resistance and p is the current. But it cannot be so because the sum of velocities along the pipe is not the same as the total velocity up the pipe. We could use v^2/2g as voltage instead but then p = Av cannot be current because it is not proportional to v^2

Comment: I already told you - electrons don't behave like water molecules. Their velocity is not important and is usually extremely low btw.

Comment: I know, i'm just thinking about hypothetical situations (breaking the laws of physics) where ohms law could be used without needing negative mass particles or gravitational repulsion. But I would like to say that their velocity is important, though negligible, it is necessary for them to have a small constant average velocity for there to be a current

Comment: Yes, they have a velocity but it doesn't matter whether you have a large number of electrons with a small velocity or a small number of electrons with a  high velocity. Anyway, I don't think you can break any laws of physics by looking at ohms law. Maybe you should instead take a look at parts of physics that are not fully understood yet e.g. dark energy.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons have to gain potential energy as they travel across each cell. Once they arrive at the positive terminal of one cell, they are pushed against the electric field to reach the negative terminal of that cell. Each time this happens the electrons gain the amount of energy specified by the cell voltage. All of this potential energy is lost to heat as the electrons now travel across the components of the circuit at constant speed.

The internal resistance of the battery just acts as a resistor in series or alternatively, as a reduction in voltage gained across the cell.

Answer (score 0):

> Because they are in some way connected to each other the electrons get
>   a final voltage of 12 volt

This might point to the root of your puzzlement; voltage is (in this context) a measure of *potential difference*.  I don't believe it's beneficial to think in terms of *electrons getting a voltage*.

The fact is that there is a potential difference (voltage), due to the separation of charge by the chemical reactions within each cell, across the terminals of each cell.

If the voltage across a cell is 2V, then moving a unit test charge from the lower potential terminal to the other requires 2J of work.

I think it's straightforward to see that if two such cells are 'stacked' in series, then moving a test charge from the lowest potential terminal to the highest potential terminal requires 2J + 2J = 4J of work and thus, the voltage across these two terminals is 4V.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the definition of potential difference:

Potential difference (for a battery) is the **work done** in moving a unit charge across the specified distance.

Let's say an electron crosses a battery of $2\text{V}$. It gets an energy of $1.6×10^{-19}\text{J}×2$, which is $3.2×10^{-19}\text{J}$.

Now the electron again crosses another $2\text{V}$ battery, it gets a further energy of $3.2×10^{-19}\text{J}$, and a total of $6.4×10^{-19}\text{J}$.

This makes sense only if you consider the equivalent voltage to be $2+2=4\text{V}$.